# EF core. When creating an MVC controller with views using EF. Creates the Create (insert) view without the inputs related to each column of the table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm trying to create an MVC controller with a view, using Scaffold. The model was created from DataBase First. The "Delete", "Edit", and "Details" views are created correctly. If I click on a record (edit) the view shows all the data. But when clicking Create New, the view doesn't show any fields, just the Create button.

[View: Create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM9EU.png)

[View: Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21b1k.png)

Comment: Paste your code as code, not as a screenshot

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scaffolding not always work correctly.
You can add fields yourself.

Code with added fields :: Create.cshtml

```
@model Library.Model.Models.Paise

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Paise</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Nombre" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Nombre" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Nombre" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Estado" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Estado" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Estado" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Observacion" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Observacion" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Observacion" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```